# Detect loaded localized resource in Android

Tags: java, android

Supose I have strings.xml, strings-es.xml and strings-ca.xml in my project. How do I know which file is loaded for the strings? Note: I don't want the OS language.

EDIT: if my device locale is Italian, I want to return English since my app is not translated into Italian.

Comment: At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html. for locale http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I know that, but as I said, I don't want that device locale.

Comment: what does this do `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()`? Provide the default device language

Comment: OK but if my OS is Spanish and my app does not have Spanish translations, what will `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()` return?

Comment: do you have strings-es.xml. check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: No, I don't have strings-es.xml. In that case, what will 'Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()' return?

Comment: it uses strings from default `strings.xml` when you don't have  `strings-es.xml`. This `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()` returns the default locale language your device has

Comment: Okay, so in that case I'll not get the loaded application language, I'll get Spanish instead of English, and that's not what I want to do :-( thanks anyway

Comment: you will get strings from `strings.xml` if you have string's in english by default. If you ahve locale spanish and if you have strings  in `strings-es.xml` then it will choose strings from `strings-es.xml`. then you have accepted wrong answer if that is not what you are looking for

Comment: No, you didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is any direct apis for that. A workaround can be, having a string resource in each xml files and this string resource can explain which resource is loaded.

For example,

`<string name="language">English</string>`

and in strings-es.xml file you can have

`<string name="language">espanol</string>`

and in the code you can check the value of this string to know the current loaded language.

However, android loads the corresponding xml file based on the OS language. So you just have to check for the corresponding OS language to know which XML file is loaded. This can acheived through `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();`

Comment: Thank you so much! that's what I realized in my first idea, but I just wanted a better option. Anyway, this works like a charm although I think is not safe (in terms of maintainability).